# How to get all the pinned messages in a telegram chat using pytelegrambotapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to retrieve all the pinned messages in telegram chat for my bot.
From the following code

```
prev_message = bot.get_chat(chat_id).pinned_message.text
```

I am able to retrieve the recent pinned messages. Is there a way to obtain all of the pinned messages as an array?.
I'm using [pytelegrambotapi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) for writing my bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official telegram bot api docs, in chat.pinned_message there is only the the last pinned message.

> The most recent pinned message (by sending date). Returned only in getChat.

Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat

So, since pyTelegramBotApi uses these http apis, I don't think you can get all the pinned messages.